# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'o'

Tags: python, scatter

I am trying to draw a scatter plot in Python with color code stored in 'color' column of dataframe. And I get invalid RGBA argument error.

Here's my code and data:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='color')  

      id         x     type     color     y
0    109       570.4       ha     r     500.8
1    110       632.4       ha     r     567.2
2    111       399.4       of     b     487.2
3    112       250.2       of     b     444.4
```

...

Comment: I'm guessing you need to specify an RGBA hex code for the color rather than the string `'color'`.

Comment: what I want to do is reading color code from datafram 'color' column. So that I can differentiate data based on color column.

Answer (score 8):

I just solved it by this code.

```
col = df['type'].map({'ha':'r', 'of':'b', 'cu':'y'})
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c=col)
```

Comment: So it seems that the argument `c` of `pd.DataFrame.plot.scatter` needs to be a list-like with the color values, rather than the name of a column containing the colors (as stated in pandas docs), right?