# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: What is causing this error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgba

I am trying to create a 3D colored bar chart using ideas from: [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950375/apply-color-map-to-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-bar3d).

First I create a 3D bar chart with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

samples = np.random.randint(91,size=(5000,2))

F = np.zeros([91,91])
for s in samples:
    F[s[0],s[1]] += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid( np.arange(F.shape[1]),
                              np.arange(F.shape[0]) )
x_data = x_data.flatten()
y_data = y_data.flatten()
z_data = F.flatten()

ax.bar3d(x_data,y_data,np.zeros(len(z_data)),1,1,z_data )
plt.show()
```

The following is the output:

[image]

Now I try to color the bars using code *verbatim* from: [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950375/apply-color-map-to-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-bar3d). Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

samples = np.random.randint(91,size=(5000,2))

F = np.zeros([91,91])
for s in samples:
    F[s[0],s[1]] += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid( np.arange(F.shape[1]),
                              np.arange(F.shape[0]) )
x_data = x_data.flatten()
y_data = y_data.flatten()
z_data = F.flatten()

dz = F
offset = dz + np.abs(dz.min())
fracs = offset.astype(float)/offset.max()
norm = colors.Normalize(fracs.min(), fracs.max())
colors = cm.jet(norm(fracs))

# colors = np.random.rand(91,91,4)

ax.bar3d(x_data,y_data,np.zeros(len(z_data)),1,1,z_data,color=colors )
plt.show()
```

However I get: `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:`

Now I am unable to debug the `Invalid RGBA argument` because I don't understand what is causing the error. I even tried to use random colors instead with `colors = np.random.rand(91,91,4)` and still the error persists.

I have checked stackoverflow posts regarding `Invalid RGBA argument` (for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521656/valueerror-invalid-rgba-argument),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802475/valueerror-invalid-rgba-argument-rgbkymc),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739673/valueerror-invalid-rgba-argument-o) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155213/matplotlib-pyplot-show-invalid-rgba)) and none of that seems to answer my problem.

I want to know what could be causing this error. I am using the standard `Anaconda` distribution for `python` on `Ubuntu Mate 16`.

Could it be that due to recent updates in python, the solution as in [the original stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950375/apply-color-map-to-mpl-toolkits-mplot3d-axes3d-bar3d) becomes obsolete?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error message is misleading. You're getting a ValueError because the shape of `colors` is wrong, not because an RGBA value is invalid.

When coloring each bar a single color, `color` should be an array of length `N`, where `N` is the number of bars. Since there are 8281 bars,

```
In [121]: x_data.shape
Out[121]: (8281,)
```

`colors` should have shape (8281, 4). But instead, the posted code generates an array of shape (91, 91, 4):

```
In [123]: colors.shape
Out[123]: (91, 91, 4)
```

So to fix the problem, use `color=colors.reshape(-1,4)`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

samples = np.random.randint(91,size=(5000,2))

F = np.zeros([91,91])
for s in samples:
    F[s[0],s[1]] += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid( np.arange(F.shape[1]),
                              np.arange(F.shape[0]) )
x_data = x_data.flatten()
y_data = y_data.flatten()
z_data = F.flatten()

dz = F
offset = dz + np.abs(dz.min())
fracs = offset.astype(float)/offset.max()
norm = colors.Normalize(fracs.min(), fracs.max())
colors = cm.jet(norm(fracs))

ax.bar3d(x_data,y_data,np.zeros(len(z_data)),1,1,z_data,color=colors.reshape(-1,4) )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `color` argument expects a 1D array, similar to all other arguments of `bar3d`.

Hence, you need to replace the line `offset = dz + np.abs(dz.min())`

by

```
offset = z_data + np.abs(z_data.min())
```

for your case. `dz` is not useful here (maybe it was in the linked example).
Note that `color=np.random.rand(len(z_data),4)` would equally work.

Then the result will be

[image]